# Which is best headless testing tool for ruby on rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jenkins, headless-browser, jasmine-headless-webkit

I have a ruby on rails application and need to run headless testing for javascript and other BDD test cases.

Suggest best available tool to run BDD tests in headless mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most popular tool is the Capybara gem:

https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

It can work with many drivers, like selenium and webkit.